# React parent component props are not passing to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

Getting data from ajax call and storing in the component state

```
_getDataFromServer(){
 reqwest({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/example/'
    , type: 'json'
    , method: 'get'
    , contentType: 'application/json'
    , crossOrigin: true
    , withCredentials: false
    , error: function (err) { }
    , success: function (resp) {
        const data = resp
        this.setState({config:data})
      }.bind(this)
  })
}

componentWillMount(){

  this._getDataFromServer()
}
```

and passing the json data in  state to child component in the render method

```
render() {
    return (
        <Panel>
          <AppDynamic uiConfig={this.state.config}/>
        </Panel>
    );
}
```

But the props are empty in the child component.i cant understand why props are not passing to child component

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Remember that the network call takes some time to return, so on the initial render the config will not yet be in the component state.

Comment: Issue is resolved. After passing the params to child component, i was storing them in the state. That the mistake , i done

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the context to`_getDataFromServer` method inside the constructor.

**Javascript**

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this._getDataFromServer = this._getDataFromServer.bind(this)
}
```